# ¿Hay diferencias entre compilar en dev c++ y vs code con Mingw?

Tags: c++

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y usaba dev c++ hasta hace poco, me cambié a vs code hace poco puesto que escuché que te ayuda a entender mejor los errores que estas cometiendo, pero, encontré que la lógica que utilicé en dev c++ para encontrar el dato mayor dentro de un arreglo de números no me estaba funcionando. El programa consiste en la recolección de datos de tres alumnos e imprimir los datos del alumno con mayor promedio. Este es el código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct alumno
{
char name[30];
int age;
float p;
}alu[3];

int main()
{
    int may;
    
    for (int i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Nombre: ";cin.getline(alu[i].name,30,'\n');
        cout<<"Edad: ";cin>>alu[i].age;
        cin.ignore();
        cout<<"Promedio: ";cin>>alu[i].p;
        cin.ignore();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        may=i;
        for(int j=i+1;j<3;j++)
        {
            if(alu[may].p<alu[j].p)
            {
                may=j;
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n\tEl alumno con mejor promedio es:   ";
    cout<<"\nNombre: "<<alu[may].name;
    cout<<"\nEdad: "<<alu[may].age;
    cout<<"\nPromedio: "<<alu[may].p;
    
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

en dev c++ lo que pasaba era que me imprimía los datos con el alumno de mayor promedio, lo que pasa ahora en vs code es que me imprime los datos del último alumno que ingrese. ¿Alguien tiene idea de que pueda estar ocurriendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas amigo estuve revisando tu código y el motivo por el que te muestra el último valor ingresado es por el uso del doble for aquí te dejo el código que realicé en este si funcionó lo de hallar el mayor promedio

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

struct Alumno{ 
char name[30];
int age;
float prom;
}alu[3];

int main(){
  for(int i=0;i<3;i++){//for de llenado de datos
  cout<<"Nombre: ";
  cin.getline(alu[i].name,30,'\n');
  cout<<"Edad: ";
  cin>>alu[i].age;
  cout<<"Promedio: ";
  cin>>alu[i].prom;
  cin.ignore();
  }
 int mayor=0;
   for(int i=0;i<3;i++){//for para encontar el mayor promedio
       if(alu[mayor].prom<alu[i+1].prom){
       mayor=i+1;
       }
   }
 cout<<endl;
 cout<<"\n El alumno con el mejor promedio es ..."<<endl;
 cout<<"\n Nombre: "<<alu[mayor].name<<endl;
 cout<<"\n Edad: "<<alu[mayor].age<<endl;
 cout<<"\n Promedio: "<<alu[mayor].prom<<endl;

 getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Y yo pensando que era el vs code, muchas gracias por la observación